# Need to validate json and do not want to use jsonparser because it is outside of python

Tags: jsonparser

I have a JSON and I want to validate it. Do we have something in python

I want to validate to put some condition like Required or Optional
{"Id": 12345, "Name":"test","Count":2,"TypeOfInstance":"m4","Version":"4.8.0-alpha",
"Key":"b8f4-82ff9d21edaa","ID":"6c58e36f4ca531",
"PPName":"false"}

Comment: I do not want to use Jsonparser because it is not part of core python. Here as part of validation I just want to check that some field are required and some fields are optional, And in case of option I want to give some value to these optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

check [kanpai](https://pypi.org/project/kanpai/).Its still in development.